# Option `headwidth=textwithmargin` of `scrlayer-scrpage` package for asymmetric page layouts

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, geometry, marginpar, scrlayer-scrpage

In the following example I am trying to extend the width of the header and the footer of the KOMA-Script class `scrbook` to include the width of the margin column:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  includemp,
  hmargin=25mm,
  marginparwidth=15mm,
  marginparsep=5mm,
  reversemp,
  asymmetric,
}

\KOMAoptions{
  usegeometry,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar,
  footwidth=textwithmarginpar,
}

\ihead{(empty)}
\ohead{makeHeader}
\ifoot{makeDocName}
\ofoot{makeFooter\quad\thepage}

\begin{document}
abc \marginpar{Note 1} \lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2-8] \marginpar{Note 2}
\end{document}
```

Although the widths seem to be adjusted correctly, the alignment of the header and the footer seem to be wrong on page 1:  The header and the footer are extended to the outer margin, not to the inner margin.  The formatting of page 2 is as I expected.

If I change the values for the `headwidth` and the `footwidth` options in `\KOMAoptions` to the following values, everything works out fine even for page 1:

```
\KOMAoptions{
  usegeometry,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep:\marginparwidth+\marginparsep,
  footwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep:\marginparwidth+\marginparsep,
}
```

Is this the intended behaviour or is this a bug?  I would have expected the first solution to work out of the box.

Maybe the `scrlayer-scrpage` package is not able to recognize the `reversemp` and `asymmetric` options of the `geometry` package correctly?